# LibreELEC : read-only files system

Tags: pulseaudio, readwrite

I'm using PI as LibreElec for Kodi.
I'm root in SSH and trying to modify, the file **/etc/pulse/default.pa** or **/etc/pulse/daemon.conf** for PulseAudio for an other problem.
But all the directory is on read-only and I don't know how change it.

**/etc** is **drwxrwxr-x**

I tried with :

`chmod +rw /etc/pulse` but tell *chmod: pulse: Read-only file system*

then `chmod +w /etc` but also tell *Read-only file system*

I'm little bit stuck with this new problem.

Comment: override settings are usually somewhere in `/storage/.config` - [this guide](https://wiki.libreelec.tv/pulseaudio) should help you with that

Comment: Saw this page but didn't realize it was written down here. Thanks for this.